# iOS Universal Links: YouTube app has no youtube.com button in status bar?

Tags: ios, youtube

I've noticed that when you open a universal link with the YouTube app, it doesn't display the 'youtube.com >' link in the top right of the status bar. Other apps I've tried, and my own, always show the link link.

As far as I can tell, this behavior is not configurable so I'm curious how YouTube has managed to disable it?

**Twitter**
[image: Twitter]

**YouTube**
[image]

Comment: Do you have an example URL that YouTube is using? I wrote a [UL Validator](https://limitless-sierra-4673.herokuapp.com/) some time ago, and just gave YouTube a try. It doesn't seem they are even configured for UL... perhaps it's just an old URL Scheme?

Comment: https://youtu.be/J5bAVKzrBzI

Interesting... when I tap and hold the link, I don't see a 'Open in "YouTube"' which you usually do with a UL.

When I tap the link, the app opens directly though, there's defiantly no scheme based open from Safari.

Comment: It's interesting that it's the .be domain, as I tried that one as well. I'm not at my Mac / iPhone testing set up to play with this right now, but I am curious as well, and will take a look tonight.

Comment: If that's something you can configure / hack to work, that would be ideal for a lot of developers. Once you've clicked that pesky right arrow (to x.com), it's difficult to get those users back.

Comment: The official methods of getting back to opening the app after clicking the arrow link are: 1) pull down the page in Safari and you'll see an option to open in the app. 2) long tap a link and choose "open in the X app". 3) You might also redirect to a universal link?